# Calculating age with decreasing year values

Tags: sequences-and-series

*This is my first question on math.stackexchange, with everything this entails.*

This question is about the perceived duration of every year as one ages. We will call
$Y_0$
the perceived duration of our first year.

As we age, every year seems shorter than the last by a ratio
$r\in]0;1]$
such that
$Y_{n+1} = Y_n.r$
which is equivalent to writing
$Y_n = Y_0.r^n$

This means that at any age $A$, we can say that we lived a perceived number of years

$P_A = \sum_{n=0}^A(Y_n.r^n) = Y_0\frac{(1-r^{A+1})}{1-r}$

Now in order to get numbers that mean anything, we need to normalize. So let's assume with a lifetime of $N$ actual years, one's perceived duration of their entire lifetime is also $N$ years. This comes down to
$P_N = N$

Now the interesting thing to do with these equations is to know how far along one is in perceived time. So for any age
$A\in[0;N]$
we want to express $P_A$ or $Y_0$ as a function of $N$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{cases}
    P_N = N\\
    P_A = \sum_{n=0}^A(Y_n.r^n)
  \end{cases}&\Rightarrow&Y_0=N\frac{1-r}{(1-r^{N+1})}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

it then follows that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{cases}
    Y_0=N\frac{1-r}{(1-r^{N+1})}\\
    P_A = Y_0\frac{(1-r^{A+1})}{1-r}
  \end{cases}&\Rightarrow&P_A = N\frac{1-r}{(1-r^{N+1})} * \frac{(1-r^{A+1})}{1-r}\\
&\Rightarrow&P_A = N\frac{(1-r^{A+1})}{(1-r^{N+1})}
\end{eqnarray*}

$P_A$ is the perceived age (in years). Let's try a few values for fun:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\begin{cases}
    N = 78, & \text{male life expectancy in France}.\\
    r = .95, & \text{less conservative estimate}.\\
    A = 25, & \text{when you started a PhD}.
\end{cases}&\Rightarrow P_A \approx 58 \text{ years old} \\ \\
&&\begin{cases}
    N = 82.5, & \text{female life expectancy in the UK}.\\
    r = .98, & \text{conservative estimate}.\\
    A = 30, & \text{when you got a kid}.
\end{cases}&\Rightarrow P_A \approx 47 \text{ years old} \\ \\
&&\begin{cases}
    N = 78.74, & \text{life expectancy in the US}.\\
    r = .99, & \text{ultra conservative estimate}.\\
    A = 45, & \text{midlife crisis}.
  \end{cases}&\Rightarrow P_A \approx 53 \text{ years old} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

**Is my reasoning correct?**

Comment: MathOverflow is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. See Math.StackExchange to ask general questions in mathematics.

Comment: Could someone migrate my question then?